# Twilio Studio help to pass a first name and play to the caller

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am creating a dialer to call patient's.

Once they answer it will ask them:

say:  This is {our company name} calling to schedule an appointment.  If this is
{{INSERT FIRST & LAST NAME }}
and you are available to scheduling your appointment please press 1

2 questions: 
1)  How can I pass the name to Twilio via REST API,  I see I can pass the number easily to dial but how can I send the number and the name to say?
2)  How do I insert the name into the studio flow?  to use TTS to say their name in between generic audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the mandatory parameters `to` and `from` you'll need to pass a third parameter named `parameters` which should be a JSON data as a string (key value pairs).

In your case, if you'd like to pass the full name as "Smith, John" then `parameters={"full_name": "Smith, John"}`.

With this, a widget in your Flow can reference the variable `{{flow.data.full_name}}`.

---

You can have more key/value pairs like: `parameters={"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"}` and reference them as `{{flow.data.first_name}}` and `{{flow.data.last_name}}`.

You did not say in your question what language and library you use but if you use Twilio's Node.js library here is a link to Twilio's docs about this: (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution?code-sample=code-create-an-execution-with-custom-parameters&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)